# Правильний правопис "не?готова"

Tags: правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо

Підкажіть, будь ласка, правильний правопис "не?готова".

Наприклад, "Вона була не?готова і не могла бути готовою до життя".

Начебто і прикметник (тоді пишемо разом), але якийсь він не такий.

Answer (score 1):

## § 33.Частки пишуться окремо:

> д) Частка **не** з прикметниками у функції присудка, якщо часткою **не**
> заперечується ознака, виражена даним словом: *Ця річка не широка*
> (заперечення), але: *Ця неширока річка впадає в Дніпро* (одне
> поняття).
>
> **Примітка.** Якщо між **не** й відповідним прикметником-присудком за змістом речення можливе **є** (**був, була́ тощо**), частку **не**
> слід писати окремо; якщо зв’язка на цьому місці порушує смисл, частку
> **не** треба писати разом: *Цей будинок не старий* (не є старий); але: *Цей будинок (є) нестарий* (тобто відносно недавно збудований).

**Розбір прикладу:**

"*Вона була не?готова і не могла бути готовою до життя*".

Перевіримо чи зміниться зміст речення, якщо між часткою **не** і прикметником вставити **була́**:
"*Вона не була готова і не могла бути готовою до життя*".

Зміст не змінився, та звучить менш гармонійно. Повернемо частку **не** в початкову позицію і розберімось чому так відбулось.

> е) Частка **не** з дієприкметниками, якщо вони мають при собі
> пояснювальні слова: *Перед будинком чорніла площа, не засаджена
> квітами*; *Ця робота ще не доведена до кінця*; *Я відклав ще не
> дописаний лист*.

**"*Вона була не готова до життя. Вона і не могла бути готовою до життя*".**

Answer (score 0):

### У цьому випадку «не» стоїть разом.

### Пояснення:

«Не» може слугувати і як частка, і як префікс. Як частку його пишуть окремо, а як префікс – разом.

Префіксом він є двох випадках: коли без нього слова не існує (невблаганний) і коли слово можна замінити синонімом: невеликий - малий.

Часткою він є у таких трьох випадках:

- коли до прикметника є протиставлення: не високий, а низький;
- коли прикметник стоїть як присудок, а «не» заперечує його ознаку (після «не» можна поставити «є»): Ця річка не глибока (не (є) глибока);
- коли перед прикметником стоять слова аж ніяк, зовсім, далеко, геть, ні до чого: далеко не найкраща робота, ні до чого не здібний.[Джерело](https://uchilka.in.ua/napysannya-ne-z-prykmetnykamy/amp/)

У реченні «Вона була не?готова і не могла бути готовою до життя» прикметник можна замінити на «безпорадний», **тому «не» треба писати разом.**

Answer (score -1):

Слово "не готовий" - це прикметник. Воно стоїть в короткій формі. Є правило, що короткі прикметники з "НЕ" пишуться так само, як і повні. Але це слово, як і деякі інші короткі прикметники, не підкоряються правилу. Вони завжди пишуться окремо. Їх не так вже й багато. Їх написання треба запам'ятати.

Не повинен, не готовий, не зобов'язаний, не має наміру, не здатний, не рад, не згоден і ін.

У пропозиціях вони найчастіше бувають присудком.

Comment: Чи не могли б ви, будь ласка, навести правило, яке це вимагає?